# RegEx for capturing digits with an optional comma

Tags: regex, string

I'm scraping this from some site and from this text " See all {a number will be there} employees".

Now this number is separated by "," as in 1,200. So what will be the regex to generalize as it could be 200 or 1,200 or 12,345,098.

#### Attempt

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Comment: i tried [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ but problem is with the "200" case when no "," will appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression would simply output our desired number:

```
([0-9,]+)
```

or

```
(\d+,?)
```

which is a capturing group, including any digit and any optional comma. If necessary, we could bound it more if we wish to.

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/6teScr/1/)

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/WTCXWT/1/)

### Advice:

[The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird):

> I think repeating the comma and the digit would be more precise like
>   for example `\d+(?:\,\d+)*` or else in a text first pattern can also
>   match a separate comma and only match separate groups with the second.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]